# UICollectionView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm struggling to find a way do something like this: 
I'm using mostly UICollectionView to make my custom lists. And this time I want to add another UICollectionView inside a UICollectionViewCell. 
The Layout is formed by a list of card, containing the informations below and inside it a list of items that came inside the same array.

Any ideias of how should I do this?

P.S: I'm not concerned about performance or something like this. So any idea would be welcome.

[image: List inside another list]

Comment: I suggest to work with it as a tableview. It should contains two sections: "pedido criado em" the header for the first section, below it, the four cells are the same type, "itens do pedido" is the header for the second section and the last tow coca-cola and fanta are cells from the same type.

Comment: As Ahmad has said, that's a tableView with multiple sections. Each section should be customized to who you want it to be

Comment: But the problem is that there are multiple "cards" and each card has this related informations and list of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this in another way. Instead of embed a UICollectionView inside another, I iterated through the array of elements and created subviews above the label.

```
if let item = info["PRODUTOSITENS"] as? [[String:Any]] {
          for produto in item {
            // All the business logic
                          let DynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:Double(cell.status.frame.origin.x), y:y, width:Double(collectionView.frame.size.width - 20.0), height:80.0))
            cell.addSubview(DynamicView)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case I see some solutions:

- Use only one `UICollectionView` and reuse needed cells for correct layout;
- Use 'UICollectionView' inside `UICollectionViewCell`. You need to add another collection view as subview in one of your cells;
- Configure subviews in your `UICollectionViewCell` as you want to showing needed content correct.

In my opinion you can choose first or last method, based on layout of your content and possibly dynamic height (if it's needed in your app).

Comment: I was thinking of return items.count + 1 in numberOfItemsInSection and check if indexpath.row is >= items.count I'll "subview" UICollectionView cell in the last cell to display the list of items (they're in the same array), but i can't figure out how can I do that exactly

Comment: Do you have models for your data? Which data structure do you have?

Comment: I have a UICollectionViewCell and the first four elements of my "card" linked to them. This was the best I could do so far